# Regular expression matching algorithm in Java

Tags: java, regex, algorithm

This [article](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) says that regexp matching in Java is slow because regexps with "back references" *cannot* be matched efficiently. The article explains *efficient* Thomson's NFA-based matching algorithm (invented in 1968) which works for regexps *without* "back references". However the `Pattern` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) says Java regexps use NFA-based approach.

Now I wonder how efficient Java regexp matching is and what algorithm it uses.

Comment: As usual: be careful with 'slow' and 'efficient'. If it's fast enough for your use case, use it, otherwise replace it. And the easiest (but maybe not the best way) to compare the speed to other solutions is a always: benchmark it.

Comment: That article was written in 2007 when, IIRC, JDK5 was being replaced by 6.  The [JDK 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) docs seem to say the same thing re use of NFAs.

Comment: Java regex uses NFA. It is very efficient. The specific problem described in the article is called [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), this can be avoided by writing patterns sensibly.

Comment: Like Neet is saying, avoid premature optimizations.  Regex is pretty fast in Java, do you need it faster?  Or is this merely your curiosity?

Comment: @trevor-e It is just my curiosity.

Comment: I love such questions :) +1

Comment: @trevor-e: I have seen regexp that take up to 15 minutes to match a given input. For example https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=175888

Comment: @AaronDigulla that looks like a console bug with Eclipse, and not a problem with the speed of the matcher algorithm: "If I remove the console and send the output to log file, there is no sluggishness."

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.regex.Pattern` uses Boyer–Moore string search algorithm

```
/* Attempts to match a slice in the input using the Boyer-Moore string
 * matching algorithm. The algorithm is based on the idea that the
 * pattern can be shifted farther ahead in the search text if it is
 * matched right to left.
 */

private void compile() {
    ----------------------
    -----------------------

   if (matchRoot instanceof Slice) {
        root = BnM.optimize(matchRoot);
        if (root == matchRoot) {
            root = hasSupplementary ? new StartS(matchRoot) : new Start(matchRoot);
        }
    } else if (matchRoot instanceof Begin || matchRoot instanceof First) {
        root = matchRoot;
    } else {
        root = hasSupplementary ? new StartS(matchRoot) : new Start(matchRoot);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is technical correct but misleading: `Pattern` does *use* Boyer-Moore, but for the special case of matching a sequence (not for regexp in general), since Boyer-Moore is a substring matching algorithm and that's all it can do. It can't match e.g. the choice or kleene closure (star) of regex. The comment in the above source says `match a slice` - looking at the rest of the source, a `Slice` does indeed seem to be a sequence of literals: [Pattern.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/c46daef6edb5/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java)